# Comparison of files of two folders

Tags: vb.net

I want to compare files of two folders in vb.net with respect of date time and size and put the odd ones in two list boxes for each folder. I am not getting through the logic. Can any one of you help me with logic or code?

Thank you.

Comment: Through the power of mind-reading, I'm going to guess one of your booleans is flipped. Hey, it's as good a guess as any other, since you didn't give us anything to go on. :p

Answer (score 1):

1. Get the [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) for each file in each of the directories.
2. Compare the required properties of each.
3. Consider what to do if there are files in one directory which are not in the other.

Answer (score 0):

Question scope is too wide to be covered on StackOverflow.

However, there is an open source project called [DirComp.NET](http://sourceforge.net/p/dircompnet/wiki/Home/).

It looks like a good starting point for you.

> DirComp.NET is a simple command-line tool written in VB.NET, which compares two directories, and either lists differences or mirrors one directory onto another. For example, it can be used to backup large file repository by maintaining a mirror copy. It lives well with existing Windows infrastructure, which already provides file shares. And finally, DirComp.NET is based on .NET Framework 2.0, which is available from Windows 2000 and up.